# Best approach at index or constraint against a computed value

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-2.1

I am using ef-core 2.1 rc1, I have a model similar to:

```
public class ChildModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Resource { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public ParentModel Parent { get; set; }
}
```

The resulting schema incorporates the `ParentId` FK int column on the associated table.

I have a unique index across `Resource`, `Role`, `Category` and `ParentId`, however I now need to enforce a new case such that for each grouping of similar `Resource` and `Role` values, only one `Category` exists per `ParentId`.

This differs from the simple unique constraint which allows duplicate sets of `Resource`, `Role` and`ParentId` to vary by `Category` only.

I have looked at computed columns which I thought if persisted could be used to generate a unique index across `Resource+Role`, `Category` and `ParentId`, but I am unable to create this scenario as EF complains that an index cannot be created across a computed column.

For example, attempting to insert two rows with the following data yields a constraint violation based on the existing index:

```
INSERT INTO [ChildModel]
    ([Resource] ,[Role] ,[Category], [ParentId])
VALUES
    ('Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz', 1),
    ('Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz', 1);
```

That satisfied the original data integrity needs, however now the following data must also throw a constraint violation:

```
INSERT INTO [ChildModel]
    ([Resource] ,[Role] ,[Category], [ParentId])
VALUES
    ('Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz', 1),
    ('Foo', 'Bar', 'Bof', 1);
```

How can this be achieved preferably at the database level only without modifying the models and introducing properties?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your description. Could you provide some sample data and then some sample additional values that should/should not be allowed based on that sample data please?

Comment: Sure, the original question has been updated.